# How to extend TFS 2008 team explorer query builder and results grid

Tags: tfs, tfs-2008

Is it possible to extend the Team Explorer 2008 Query Builder and Query result grid using TFS SDK , I have a requirement where i like to add some custom columns and get the output in the result grid in a hierarchical structure, whether this is possible or do i have to write these functionalities from scratch. Is there any API documentation available for team explorer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're going to have much luck doing this with the stock query result grid.  You could potentially write your own, using the TFS API, and create it as a Visual Studio add-in.

Found some details to get a list of the queries from TFS.  This is if you have Visual Studio 2010

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Enumerate%20Stored%20Queries

Alternatively (and a bit more easily), you can use code like this to get the queries. However, it uses some deprecated code.  It is, however, designed for TFS 2008 and Visual Studio 2008:

```
        TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://tfs:8080");
        WorkItemStore wis = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

        var project = wis.Projects[0];

        for(int i=0; i<project.StoredQueries.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(project.StoredQueries[i].Name);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply robaticus, i too think so, i cant find any relevant materials on this, i do have one more doubt on this, is there any way i could get the query object created with the query builder so i can write a custom code based on the query and export to excel with the hierarchies.

Comment: see my edit for a link to how to get a list of the queries, and some code.